# Weight limit chart in Android

Tags: android, graph, charts, percentage

I have created following chart in Android, but I am unable to adjust value with percentage.

[image]

Red color is upper limit of weight that is 20.64
Yellow color is lower limit of weight that is 13.39

Current weight of child is 18 so it need to show between upper limit and lower limit in Green color.

Please! let me know how to calculate exact percentage of each parameter. I have following parameters.

```
upperLimit
lowerLimit
normalLimit
currentValue
```

Currently I am facing to adjust currentValue.

**OR show me any related chart or tutorial.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed this chart and upload on GitHub.
[Android Weight Limit Chart](https://github.com/atifmahmood29/android-weight-limit-chart)